# Request Body is null in Post request in Web Api

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api2

I have a action method like this

```
[ResponseType(typeof(DiaryDeviceDTO))]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Device/Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(DeviceRegistration deviceRegistration)
{
    if (deviceRegistration == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Request body is null");
    }
    
    DiaryDevice device = await _deviceBl.Register(deviceRegistration.RegistrationCode);
    var deviceDto = Mapper.Map<DiaryDevice, DiaryDeviceDTO>(device);
    return Ok(deviceDto);
}
```

When I call this api from **PostMan** with below request body, I get `deviceRegistration` object as `null`. I also set `ContentType` header as `application/json`

```
{
    "ApiKey" : "apikey",
    "RegistrationCode" : "123",
    "ImeiNo" : "12345"
}
```

Then I try to read the request content as below-

```
string body = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This time I also get `body = ""`

But when I run my Unit test I get `deviceRegistration` as I wanted. So what's wrong with my code. Why my code only work for unit testing. I am using Web Api 2.2

### Update / Solution

Sorry for asking this question. Actually it was my mistake. I accidentally read the request body inside `Application_BeginRequest()` method for logging. I move those logging codes inside `Application_EndRequest()` method and everything becomes ok.

Comment: Try adding `[FromBody]` attribute in front of parameter

Comment: Tried, but no luck. :(

Comment: Please show how you are making the request.

Comment: also show DeviceRegistration class

Comment: @EmdadulSawon, just to be sure, that is the complete class? You don't have it decorated `[serializable]` right? It might help if you implement a `DelegatingHandler` so you can intercept the request/response and see exactly what it looks like.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. It was our mistake. We read the request body in Application_BeginRequest() method. So request body become null.

Answer (score 4):

Given what you've shown, this should work for the requests to `api/device/register`

```
[ResponseType(typeof(DiaryDeviceDTO))]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Device/Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register([FromBody]DeviceRegistration deviceRegistration)
{
    if (deviceRegistration == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Request body is null");
    }

    DiaryDevice device = await _deviceBl.Register(deviceRegistration.RegistrationCode);
    var deviceDto = Mapper.Map<DiaryDevice, DiaryDeviceDTO>(device);
    return Ok(deviceDto);
}
```

Note the [FromBody] attribute.